# Update multiple images of posts in laravel with hasMany relation

Tags: database, laravel, file-upload, eloquent

I'm trying store multiple images related to blog post.
I have two tables:

**posts**

**post_images**

post_images table contains three column

1. id
2. post_id
3. thumbnail (name of image)

Now I want to update my images related to my blog post. It is difficult for me to update.

My controller method for save data is as below.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validatePost();
    $featured = $request->featured;
    $featured_new_name = time() . $featured->getClientOriginalName();
    $featured->move('uploads/posts/featured', $featured_new_name);

    $post = Post::create([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'title' => $request->title,
        'info' => $request->info,
        'content' => $request->content,
        'featured' => 'uploads/posts/featured/' . $featured_new_name,
        'category_id' => $request->category_id,
        'slug' => Str::slug($request->title, '-')
    ]);

    $post->tags()->attach($request->tags);

    if ($request->hasFile('thumbnail')) {
        $slug = $post->slug;
        $path =  public_path('uploads/posts/thumbnail/' . $slug . '');
        if (!File::isDirectory($path)) {
            File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
        }
        $thumbnails = $request->thumbnail;
        foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
            $thumbnail_new_name = time() . $thumbnail->getClientOriginalName();
            $thumbnail->move('uploads/posts/thumbnail/' . $slug . '', $thumbnail_new_name);
            $thumbnailName = 'uploads/posts/thumbnail/' . $slug . '/' . $thumbnail_new_name;
            PostImage::create([
                'post_id' => $post->id,
                'thumbnail' => $thumbnailName
            ]);
        }
    }
    return redirect(route('posts'))->with('message', 'Post Saved Successfully.');
}
```

Can anyone help me how can i update my images data?

Comment: Describe what do you want updated. It is unclear what kind of update you are talking about.

Comment: I want to update post data and images related to that posts.

Comment: Where is exact problem? What is error log?